# MSYS2 /pacman can't install any program

Tags: msys2, pacman-package-manager

How to solve this error ?

> error: failed  retrieving file ... from ....

[image: terminal error]

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29784253/148889

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to update MSYS2 these days is to run `update-core`, follow its instructions, and then run `pacman -Su`.  Hopefully that solves your problem.